# Redirect to View from AJAX call on error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, redirect

***Problem:***
I would like to load a partialview into a DIV when success, but in case an error happened I need to redirect to the view home page. The issue is that  the Redirect to Action is also loaded into the div `resultdisplay`.
How should I manage the errorhandling to Redirect to fullviews in case of error?

***Code:***

*Ajax call:*

```
function GetFilteredValuesCallback(values) {
    var data = JSON.stringify(values);
    var url = '/Controller/Action';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        data: { filter: data },
        success: function (result) {
            $('#resultDisplay').html(result);
        }
    });
}
```

*Action:*

```
public ActionResult Action(string filter)
{
    MyModel model = null;
    try
    {
        // Do stuff with my model ...
        throw new Exception("ERROR!");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // In case of error redirect to home page
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return PartialView("_PartialView", model);
}
```

Comment: Server-side `RedirectToAction` returns a redirect response to the browser, which Ajax then promptly ignores. You need to return metadata to your Ajax call, so that it then knows to change the page to a new URL (or use an error instead and redirect in the `error:` callback).

Comment: Ajax calls stay on the same page. Instead of catching the exception, let it happen and then in the ajax `.fail()` callback, use `location.href='yourUrl';`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well instead of redirecting in controller you can just send information back to client ajax request and handle redirection here as below:

```
function GetFilteredValuesCallback(values) {
    var data = JSON.stringify(values);
    var url = '/Controller/Action';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        data: { filter: data },
        success: function (result) {
            if(result.message==="Failed")
                location.href = "yoururl"
            else
                $('#resultDisplay').html(result);
        },
        error:function(result)
        {
           //handle any errors          
        }
    });
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Action(string filter)
{
    MyModel model = null;
    try
    {
        // Do stuff with my model ...
        throw new Exception("ERROR!");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // In case of error 
        return Json(new{message="Failed"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); //Send  a message back
    }
    return PartialView("_PartialView", model);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks @StephenMuecke for the suggestion to handle this in more elegant way which can be done as below:

**JS**

```
function GetFilteredValuesCallback(values) {
    var data = JSON.stringify(values);
    var url = '/Controller/Action';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        data: { filter: data },
        success: function (result) {
             $('#resultDisplay').html(result);
        },
        error:function(result)
        {
           location.href("yoururl");
        }
    });
 }
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Action(string filter)
{
    MyModel model = null;
    try
    {
        // Do stuff with my model ...
        throw new Exception("ERROR!");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // In case of error 
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(500);
    }
    return PartialView("_PartialView", model);
}
```